# Can't use Color Picker Extension in VS Code. [processBridge]: Error: Cannot get NPM

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm

*Specs:*

- Windows 10 Home 21H2
- CPU Intel i7-8700k
- Motherboard ASUS Prime Z370-P II
- Visual Studio Code v1.65.2
- Node v16.14.2.
- npm v8.5.0

---

*The Problem:*

[When I run Pick Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oarAa.jpg) ...
[This happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJgG2.jpg)

*How I got here:*

I installed node (and npm) as part of a course, from the official website, to use a TypeScript compiler.
In the process *Chocolatey* and something about *Python* was also installed. I think I remember seeing some errors in the script, but I'm very new to all of this. Despite that, both are in paths, as shown later.

Also had to use PowerShell and run
[Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juB0H.jpg)

I checked the installation
[Node version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE6yV.jpg)

Now this is what happens when I try to use the Color Picker extension. First, the installation guide says
**[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbwdR.jpg).**

- PATH is ok, as shown in the following pictures.
- Node Version Manager? Don't remember using that.
- Command Pallete, ext install, "Color Picker" not on the list.

*Paths:*
[User Variables Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dOCF.jpg) and
[System Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI0vh.jpg)

*VS Code:*
[Trying ext install in the command pallete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9c8s.jpg)

I'm very sorry for this last screenshots in spanish.

---

Lastly I found this old issue on GitHub but I couldn't solve my problem with it:

(Gonna leave link in the comments as I can't go beyond 8 links in my post.)

---

Comment: This is the link to the GitHub issue https://github.com/anseki/vscode-color/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this extension? Probably something buggy that will cause you problems with every upgrade. You already have a similar and cleaner solution as a VSCode default:

[image: Screenshot of color picker]

Just hover over a color and the little square icon next to it in a CSS or SASS/SCSS file, and you'll see the picker pop up. For changing from RGB(A) to HEX and other types, just click the header where you see rgba(84, ...) in the screenshot.

Comment: I don't **need** it, but I'm wondering why its not working and if I installed node correctly. Also I didn't know you could change type by clicking the header, thank you very much.